# How can I define a d-dimensional metric on mathematica with abstract components?

Tags: physics, geometry, xact, gr

I want to define on Mathematica the (d+1)-dimensional metric:

$ ds^2 =G_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}= 2tdt^2 + g_{ij}(t,x)dx^idx^j $

where latin indices go $i,j=1,...,d-1$ and $g_{ij}$ are unknown functions of $t$ and $x^k$. And then I would like to compute the Christoffel symbols and the Ricci tensor components of $G_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of $g_{ij}$ and its derivatives.

But xTensor can't compute components and xCoba can't understand the abstract  indices in $g_{ij}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To use xAct, you're going to need to specify an integer value for d, for starters. What dimension did you have in mind? I also recall that xCoba's documentation does contain examples for doing Christoffel/Ricci etc. for several metrics. It's probably not so much the indices, but the unknown functions that may give you trouble. Of course you can also do these computations with your own code. There are other questions on this site where Christoffel/etc. code has been provided in the answers.